# Testing an h-bridge using the power supply and/or signal generator to control a DC motor

Tags: motor, pwm, dc-motor, h-bridge, brushless-dc-motor

I'm using the DRV8836 (datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8836.pdf)) from Texas Instruments and can't seem to get it to work. Does it require a PWM (pulse from the signal generator) or am I able to drive it with only the DC power supply? I'm a bit confused with how this chip works in terms of what type of input the PHASE pin expects. I know that the ENABLE pin can just be pulled high by a DC power supply. I am using the PHASE/ENABLE mode, but what is the difference between this mode and the IN/IN mode?

What I want to do is to control a DC motor with this H-bridge and a microcontroller, but for now I just want to test if I have the chip soldered onto its adapter board properly, which I have on a breadboard.

[image]

Here is my set-up:
[image: second]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between PH/EN mode and IN/IN mode can be understood by looking at the truth table given in the data sheet (pg 7). When Under IN/IN mode you are essentially controlling each output port individually. Hence energizing one output port and leaving the other open will operate the motor in a particular direction.

Under PH/EN mode what you are doing is allowing the logic circuit inside to control the direction of movement, instead of energizing and de-energizing each coil individually. Hence the truth table for PH/EN mode is much smaller. For driving a DC motor PH/EN mode is sufficient.

To check if the board is working Give VCC and ground as usual.

1) set mode to 1

2) AIN1 = 0

3) AIN2 = 1

4) nsleep = 1

With the motor connected across AOUT1 and AOUT2 the motor should run in the forward direction.

If you wish to provide PWM to control the speed of the motor send a pwm signal to AIN2 which is the enable pin (AIN2 is the phase/direction pin). By changing the Duty cycle you may vary the speed.

You can also confirm that this method works by looking at the timing diagram given in page 6.

Comment: I would like to drive the motor at a constant speed. From your answer my understanding then is that I don't need the signal generator at all for PWM. I can simply use the DC power supply? I have connected the circuit as you suggested but what happens is the motor does not run and the chip heats up very quickly (so I disconnect it immediately as soon as this happens).

Comment: What could the problem be? I tested for shorts between the leads of the adapter board but since the chip itself has no leads on the package (DFN), I can't tell if the chip is soldered onto the board correctly.

Comment: Can we see a picture of the set up? Make sure Vcc is powered by a 5V source. And provide an input capacitor. Would'nt know why it would overheat, sounds weird.

Comment: What's the motor rating?

Comment: It's a 13 V motor and I've attached an image to the post now. Red and black are what you would expect, but I don't use the red rails on the edge of the breadboard because I have another circuit connected to the same board. They share the same ground but I only power the one pictured. However I only tried supplying 2V to the chip - I'm afraid 5V might blow something if I did wire something wrong.

Comment: Also, I tried running the motor directly from the power supply at 2V, it stills runs but very slowly, so I know this is enough to drive it despite it being rated at 13 V.

Comment: That could be the problem, I know it says the minimum operating voltage is 2V but the chip has undervoltage lockout protection which gets triggered at 2 volts or below. Try supplying 3-4 volts at least. Plus are you running the logic high at 2 volts also?

Comment: Hmm alright I'll try that first thing in the morning (it's 3am here now). Yes the logic high is using the 2V as well.

Comment: Use 5V for logic high. And keep it isolated from the supply (I generally like to do this). Plus i cant see any motor connections?

Comment: The motor was connected across where the diode is in the photo. I'll definitely try out your suggestions later today and update you on how it goes, thank you

Comment: Your use of the flyback diode will cause problems as this may short both the output terminals. Connect the flyback diodes in the following way. http://www.robotroom.com/HBridge.html

Comment: Would the warning on that page apply to my application at all? I experience what the author describes - the motor doesn't run and the chip heats up rapidly - but the datasheet for my chip indicates I can drive the motors directly without external FETs. My intuition is that the warning wouldn't apply but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: no need of external FETs, just wanted you to look at the flyback diode placement and correct it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23294/discussion-between-sada93-and-christina).